# Why does Python not read the end of line character when opening utf-16 file?

Tags: python, utf-16

I'm concatenating two text files, one is utf-16. When read the lines from the files, and split them, the utf-16 file does not have an end of line. Everything goes into one line, so I have to specify an end of line character. Any ideas why ?

Below code that is working, but I want to know why do I need to have end of line for utf-16.

```py
with open(file_temp, 'w') as outfile:
    with open(file_normal) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.split(",")[0]) # auto end of line
    with open(file_utf16, encoding='utf-16') as infile: # different file format
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.split(",")[0] + "\n") # needs end of line char for some reason ?
```

I expected the end of line character to be present in the utf-16 file when reading with correct encoding.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, the `split` range for `file_normal` included the **end of line** while the `split` range for `file_utf16` did not include the **end of line**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newline has nothing to do with the encoding as such

```
with open("someFile_utf16.txt", "w",encoding='utf-16') as infile:
    for x in range(10):
        infile.write(str(x))

with open("someFile_normal.txt", "w") as infile:
    for x in range(10):
        infile.write(str(x))
```

Both had the same data in the files

```
0123456789
```

The only possible explanation is that the normal file had the **end of line** written into it, whereas the utf-16 file did not have it

For more reference

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Both files had the **end of line**, but I mistakenly thought `split` ignores **end of line** and only looks at text, and that `write` generates the **end of line**.